# problem with getting z-index to work

Tags: css, z-index

i am trying to create a sub navigation which is followed by seperator line (div with a bottom border) which acts as a visual cue.

but the line is appearing below the menu items. not sure how to get it right

http://jsbin.com/ijewi4

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how you want it to turn out here, what do you mean with "followed"?

Comment: the horizontal line - if u see it clearly. it goes under the buttons. it should either sit exactly at the bottom of the button tabs or above it so that it looks more of a seamless design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about what you want to achieve but if you want to make the div "sit exactly at the bottom of the button tabs":

http://jsbin.com/ijewi4/3

Comment: basically when you put menu with padding, it make following divs moved up. if you check the code you'll find that padding 4 px = #clear 1px + #separator 3px. and you don't need to use z-index :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like the hr element, i always use a div with a border-bottom.

That may work for you too.

Comment: ouch. i am using the same. to explain i mentioned it as hr :d will edit the post :D

Comment: that changes it... i'll look into it.